# Break down of requests to a specific endpoint by the originating service name in Istio

Tags: kubernetes, istio, datadog, micrometer

I'm running a Spring Boot app within an Istio service mesh on k8s, and I'd like to record custom Datadog metrics on a per endpoint basis on which service calls it and how many times. For that, I need to know the name of the service that's sending a request. How do I extract source service name from Istio? I specifically want to extract it from some Spring Boot servlet filter, if possible.

It seems like it's possible to get `source.principal`, but is there a service name?

Answer (score 1):

You want a dependable way to extract the name of the service sending an HTTP request to your service directly within your Spring Boot application, *without* relying on [Istio](https://istio.io/)'s external telemetry or metrics.

You might then need to depend on standardized [HTTP headers](https://istiobyexample.dev/response-headers/) that Istio injects into requests for tracing purposes.

Istio, by default, uses [Envoy proxy](https://www.envoyproxy.io/) (see "[Inside Envoy: The Proxy for the Future](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uaksVVHDhYU)") for sidecars, which supports tracing and [injects headers](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http/http_conn_man/headers.html) that can be used to infer the source of a request.
Headers like `x-request-id`, `x-b3-traceid`, `x-b3-spanid`, `x-b3-parentspanid`, and `x-b3-sampled` are commonly used for tracing.
But: these headers do *not* directly include the source service name. Instead, Istio's tracing headers are designed for distributed tracing systems (like [Jaeger](https://www.jaegertracing.io/) or [Zipkin](https://zipkin.io/)) to track requests across services.

So, to directly get the source service name within your application, you would need to configure Istio to forward *additional* headers containing this information, as mentioned before.
If you are not looking to use [`EnvoyFilter`](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/envoy-filter/) to inject custom headers (which was the suggested workaround), you would be limited to using headers that are already present or configuring your services to explicitly send their names in a custom header.

Assuming you have a way to make sure the source service name is included in the request headers (either via Istio configuration, which requires custom setup like EnvoyFilter, or by convention across your services), you can extract this information in Spring Boot with:

```java
import org.springframework.web.filter.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

public class CustomRequestLoggingFilter extends CommonsRequestLoggingFilter {

    @Override
    protected void beforeRequest(HttpServletRequest request, String message) {
        // Assuming the source service name is sent in a custom header `X-Source-Service`
        String sourceServiceName = request.getHeader("X-Source-Service");
        if (sourceServiceName != null) {
            // Log the source service name or use it as needed
            logger.info("Request from service: " + sourceServiceName);
        }
    }
}
```

With Kotlin:

```kotlin
import org.springframework.web.filter.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest

class CustomRequestLoggingFilter : CommonsRequestLoggingFilter() {

    override fun beforeRequest(request: HttpServletRequest, message: String) {
        // Assuming the source service name is sent in a custom header `X-Source-Service`
        val sourceServiceName = request.getHeader("X-Source-Service")
        sourceServiceName?.let {
            // Log the source service name or use it as needed
            logger.info("Request from service: $it")
        }
    }
}
```

Again: either your service injects its name in the request headers or you configure Istio to inject the source service name into the headers.

To use an `EnvoyFilter` for injecting the source service name into requests as an `X-Source-Service` header, you will need administrative access to your Istio installation to apply the `EnvoyFilter` configuration.

Here is an example of an `EnvoyFilter` using a Lua script to inject the `X-Source-Service` header into incoming requests to your target service.
That header will contain the name of the workload (i.e., the service name) sending the request.
(inspired from : [`istio/istio` `tests/integration/ambient/baseline_test.go#TestWaypointEnvoyFilter()`](https://github.com/istio/istio/blob/7d014d23f46867e9f8740b20a00593dd1b92767c/tests/integration/ambient/baseline_test.go#L392)).

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: inject-source-service-header
  namespace: target-service-namespace # Change this to the namespace of your target service
spec:
  workloadSelector:
    labels:
      app: target-service-name # Change this to the label of your target service
  configPatches:
    - applyTo: HTTP_FILTER
      match:
        context: SIDECAR_INBOUND
        listener:
          filterChain:
            filter:
              name: "envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager"
              subFilter:
                name: "envoy.filters.http.router"
      patch:
        operation: INSERT_FIRST
        value:
          name: envoy.lua
          typed_config:
            "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.lua.v3.Lua
            inlineCode: |
              function envoy_on_request(request_handle)
                local source_service = request_handle:connection():ssl():subjectLocalCertificate():getSubjectAlternativeNames()[1]
                request_handle:headers():add("X-Source-Service", source_service)
              end
```

The `namespace` should be set to the namespace where your target service is deployed.
And the `workloadSelector.labels` selects the specific workload(s) (e.g., your target Spring Boot application) to which the EnvoyFilter applies, based on Kubernetes labels.
The Lua script within `inlineCode` extracts the service name from the source service's SSL certificate (assuming mutual TLS is enabled and properly configured in your service mesh) and adds it to the incoming request headers as `X-Source-Service`. That would assume that the subject alternative name (SAN) in the certificate is used to identify the service, which is common in Istio deployments using [mutual TLS (mTLS)](https://istio.io/latest/docs/concepts/security/#mutual-tls-authentication).

---

> Is there a way to get this out of request in Spring Boot, rather than in EnvoyFilter / Lua?"

Extract the name of the calling service directly within a Spring Boot application without using an `EnvoyFilter` or Lua scripting?
I do not think so.
Istio, and more broadly service meshes, primarily focus on transparently managing service-to-service communication without requiring changes to the application code. That means that details about the calling service, such as its name, are *not* automatically passed to the called service in a way that is directly accessible by application code, like in Spring Boot, without explicitly configuring the mesh or the calling service to do so.

Without using an `EnvoyFilter` or Lua scripting to inject custom headers, you would:

- either rely on standard HTTP headers that might indirectly indicate the calling service, such as `Referer`, `User-Agent`, or other headers. However, these headers are not reliable for service identification and can be easily spoofed.
- or modify the calling services to include a custom header with their service name when making requests. That requires changes across *all* services in your architecture to make sure they include this header in their outbound requests.

  For example, when Service A calls Service B, Service A includes a header like `X-Calling-Service: ServiceA` in its requests. Then, in your Spring Boot application (Service B), you can easily extract this header:

  ```java
  @GetMapping("/your-endpoint")
  public ResponseEntity<?> yourEndpoint(HttpServletRequest request) {
       String callingService = request.getHeader("X-Calling-Service");
       // Use the callingService variable as needed
       return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
  }
  ```
- or try and get metadata about workloads through Itio's APIs and the [Kiali dashboard](https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/integrations/kiali/), but this is more about observability from an operational perspective rather than something accessible at runtime within application code.

So the most straightforward and reliable method remains to have calling services include a custom header with their name in requests, making sure this is a part of your service-to-service communication contract.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is their a way to  get this out of request in Spring Boot, rather than in EnvoyFilter / Lua?